Prevent "Mesh Boolean" from taking intersecting objects material?
Ok I have searched quite a while for this, so I hope I am not overlooking an obvious option.
I want to model some nails in a wood plank. To make a bit more realistic looking I wanted to add some deformation of the wood around the nails, however I did not want to manually model more geometry (and I wanted to automate copying and placing multiple nails) so I landed on using the "Mesh Boolean" geometry node.
Here is the setup:

Basically it should take all the nails in the "Nails_1" sub-collection, scale and offset it slightly. This works alright for the most part:

However, if I hide the nail I see that the material on the intersection is take from the nail:

As far as I could find out, this is expected behavior. Nonetheless, I am wondering if it is possible to prevent this and use the original wood material.

Fixed it temporarily with a Set Material node of the intersection mesh, but that seems not like a really good solution?

Yah, no I think that's the way to do it.
